# Using get_posts() with tax_query parameter set isn't working with attachments

Tags: taxonomy, get-posts, tax-query

I'm working on a project that requires searching for attachments with a given taxonomy-slug pair (in this case, `category`=`javascript`). I'm using `get_posts()` with `tax_query` set to achieve this, but it is returning zilch.

The array being passed to get_posts() is the following:

```
array(8) {
  ["tax_query"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["taxonomy"]=>
      string(8) "category"
      ["field"]=>
      string(4) "slug"
      ["term"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "javascript"
      }
    }
  }
  ["numberposts"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["orderby"]=>
  string(10) "menu_order"
  ["order"]=>
  string(3) "ASC"
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "inherit" // 'any' also tried
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(10) "attachment"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(34) "application,video,text,audio,image"
  ["post_parent"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

There is an image in category `JavaScript` (which has `javascript` as the slug), but it is not being returned.

Also, on the off chance it's relevant, category is being set through use of [Media Categories](http://wordpress.org/plugins/media-categories-2/).

**EDIT:** `post_status=>inherit` and `post_status=>any` were tried with no change in the end result.

**EDIT 2:** Creating a new `WP_Query` object, leaving out the `meta_query` creates valid SQL, but including `meta_query` adds this: `AND 0 = 1`, which obviously makes the entire query return nothing. The entire SQL generated is below:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  cms_posts.ID 
FROM cms_posts  
WHERE 1=1  
AND 0 = 1 
AND (
    cms_posts.post_mime_type 
    LIKE 'application/%' 
    OR cms_posts.post_mime_type 
    LIKE 'video/%' 
    OR cms_posts.post_mime_type 
    LIKE 'text/%' 
    OR cms_posts.post_mime_type 
    LIKE 'audio/%' 
    OR cms_posts.post_mime_type 
    LIKE 'image/%')  
AND cms_posts.post_type = 'attachment' 
AND (cms_posts.post_status <> 'trash' 
    AND cms_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft' 
    AND cms_posts.post_status <> 'spam') 
GROUP BY cms_posts.ID 
ORDER BY cms_posts.menu_order 
ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Does removing the taxonomy query return any results?

Comment: Just noticed: you said that the taxonomy was a category but the query above is looking for a post tag.  Which one is it supposed to be?

Comment: Removing the taxonomy query returns all attachments meeting the rest of the query. And sorry about the `post_tag`. Mistakenly made it in when I was including the `post_status`.

Comment: it's probably easier to debug using wp_query rather than get_posts, then you can inspect the query object and see the actual SQL being generated and sent to the database

Comment: @Milo Well, just modified the original question with the results of creating a WP_Query with the attributes listed. Even more baffling than before.

Comment: it should be `terms` not `term` in the tax query.  Edited my answer to show this.  This is probably why you are getting `0 = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've tried this but try adding `post_status => inherit` to your query.  I've found that `get_posts` defaults to `publish` and therefore will not return any attachments, since their `post_status` is always `inherit`.  The codex page on [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Usage) confirms this.

Edit: looking at your query again, you have `term` in the `tax_query` where it should be `terms`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Logical suggestion, but didn't change anything. Also tried `post_status=>any`, what the `get_posts` codex entry uses in one of the attachment queries.

Comment: Well I'll be buggered... You're correct. After pluralizing `term` to `terms`, everything is working how I would expect. Thanks!